# Multiple File Upload Joomla

Tags: php, file, file-upload, joomla, joomla2.5

Can I do a multiple file upload in my Joomla component using PHP? If so how can I do it?

Comment: We don't do your work for you. You should atleast try something yourself

Comment: yeah I know. I asked because I don't know. All I ask for is guidance. I didn't ask you to code for me. That's why I specifically I asked for a SNIPPET. Not the whole CODE.

Comment: well if you are interested in a free SWFUpload component that will be easy to integrate into your component, then you can download our one. http://joomjunk.co.uk/products/component-home/swfupload.html

Comment: Thanks for the support. Let me try it out. BTW is it possible to integrate this component into my component.

Comment: yes, it is possible. This is what we built this extension for. Tried to make it as simple as possible to make it easy to integrate ;)

Comment: that cannot be done. I want to have that option at the backend.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple file upload is already part of the media manager and JFormFieldMedia in core Joomla 2.5 and there is the flash uploader in 1.5/2.5 if a site has enabled it. So I would say extend that or copy the code to implement.